# Is javadoc html or xhtml?

Tags: html, xhtml, javadoc

I was typing some Javadoc into IntelliJ this morning and used a <br> tag, which IntelliJ autocompleted to <br>|</br> in its usual helpful way... but I'm under the impression that <br> is defined not to be a container:

http://www.washington.edu/accessit/webdesign/student/unit2/common_tags.htm says:

> A few tags are called non-container tags, because they don't contain
>   any content - they stand alone. Examples are images and line breaks.
>   XHTML requires that all open tags must be closed, even if they're not
>   container tags. Therefore, non-container tags end in />. For example,
>   the tag for a line break is <br />.

So is Javadoc HTML or XHTML? It seems to me IntelliJ should be completing <br> to <br /> or leaving it alone.

Comment: open tag <br> must be closed, typing <br /> is a common solution.

Comment: As I cited above, whether <br> needs closing apparently depends on whether you're writing in HTML (should NOT) or XHTML (should), hence my question as to WHICH ONE of the formats is used in javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

> Format of a Doc Comment A doc comment is written in HTML and must
>   precede a class, field, constructor or method declaration. It is made
>   up of two parts -- a description followed by block tags. In this
>   example, the block tags are @param, @return, and @see.